# What are the varnas of Vashishta and Arundhati?

Tags: varna

[Arundhati](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arundhati_(Hinduism)). is the wife of the sage [Vashistha](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasishtha), one of the seven sages (Saptarshi).

To which varna does Vashishta belong to?

To which varna does Arundhati belong to?

Comment: Do you mean Brahmin, Khastriya etc. by Varna?

Comment: @Pandya yeah...

Comment: Vashishta is mind born son of BrahmA and Arundhati was daughter of Kardama Rishi who was mind born son of BrahmA.